# trying to migrate dataase from an ec2 instance to rds using dms i'm getting this error while running test at dms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate a database from an ec2 instance to rds using dms, however i'm getting this error

> Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider  ODBC general error., Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 2003 Message: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database-1.coqzzaxujw15.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)

Below is an image from the interface of the error above.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can I recommend replacing the image with removing tabs and also hiding any resources names/account names :)

Comment: Also go through this article, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-endpoint-connectivity-failures/. Its likely that you have a security group rule on your RDS database restricting inbound access. Are all resources private (in private subnets too).